# How to filter through Model of a many-to-many field?

Tags: python, django, model, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a geofencing for a fleet of trucks. I have to associate a list of boundaries to a vehicle. On top of that one of the requirements is keep everything even once it is deleted for audit purposes. Therefore we have to implement soft delete on everything. This is where the problem lies. My many to many field does not conform to the soft delete manager, it includes both the active and the inactive records in the lookup dataset.

```
class Vehicle(SoftDeleteModel):
    routes = models.ManyToManyField('RouteBoundary', through='VehicleBoundaryMap', verbose_name=_('routes'),
                                    limit_choices_to={'active': True})


class VehicleBoundaryMap(SoftDeleteModel):
    vehicle = models.ForeignKey(Vehicle, verbose_name="vehicle")
    route_boundary = models.ForeignKey(RouteBoundary, verbose_name="route boundary")
    # ... more stuff here

    alive = SoftDeleteManager()


class SoftDeleteManager(models.Manager):

    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self):
        return SoftDeleteQuerySet(self.model).filter(active=True)
```

As you see above I tried to make sure the default manager is a soft delete manager (ie. filter for active records only) and also try use limit limit_choices_to but that turn out to field the foreign model only not the "through" model I wanted. If you have any suggestions or recommendation I would love to hear from you.

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of implementing soft deletes yourself, use something like [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion).

Comment: That soft delete already implemented everywhere already, I cannot change it anymore. I wish we would use reversion, it would save us lots of head ache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First problem: your use of `limit_choices_to` won't work because as the [documentation says](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to):

> `limit_choices_to` has no effect when used on a `ManyToManyField` with a custom intermediate table specified using the `through` parameter.

You are using `through` so `limit_choices_to` has no effect.

Second problem: your use of `use_for_related_fields = True` is also ineffective. The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#controlling-automatic-manager-types) says about this attribute:

> If this attribute is set on the *default* manager for a model (only the default manager is considered in these situations), Django will use that class whenever it needs to automatically create a manager for the class.

Your custom manager is assigned to the `alive` attribute of `VehicleBoundaryMap` rather than `objects` so it is ignored.

The one way I see which may work would be:

1. Create a [proxy model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models) for `VehicleBoundaryMap`. Let's call it `VehicleBoundaryMapProxy`. Set it so that its default manager is `SoftDeleteManager()` Something like:

   ```
   class VehicleBoundaryMapProxy(VehicleBoundaryMap):
       class Meta:
           proxy = True

       objects = SoftDeleteManager()
   ```
2. Have `through='VehicleBounddaryMapProxy'` on your `ManyToManyField`:

   ```
    class Vehicle(SoftDeleteModel):
       routes = models.ManyToManyField('RouteBoundary', 
                                        through='VehicleBoundaryMapProxy', 
                                        verbose_name=_('routes'))
   ```

Comment: Let me give this a try, so far it looks promising.

Comment: It works quite beautifully, thanks Louis for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

What about if you just do:

```
class Vehicle(SoftDeleteModel):
    #you can even remove that field
    #routes = models.ManyToManyField('RouteBoundary', through='VehicleBoundaryMap', verbose_name=_('routes'),
    #                                limit_choices_to={'active': True})

    @property
    def routes(self):
        return RouteBoundary.objects.filter(
            vehicleboundarymap__active=True,
            vehicleboundarymap__vehicle=self,
        )
```

And now instead of `vehicle.routes.clear()` use `vehicle.vehicleboundarymap_set.delete()`. You will only lose the reverse relation (`RouteBoundary.vehicles`) but you can implement it back using the same fashion.

The rest of the `M2M field` features are [disabled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) anyway because of the intermediate model.

Comment: I like your idea, it kinna outside of the box. However since I can't use prefetch on it, that a big no no for me.